# Calling Super in Java Constructors

Tags: java, constructor, super

I know that super is called when you create a subclass in Java. But is super called in every constructor, or only in the first constructor of the subclass?

Thanks

Comment: Please give a concrete example of your question, ideally with some indication of what you've tried in order to answer it for yourself.

Comment: Note that you don't need to call super in all cases. Give some examples of what you mean.

Comment: What do you mean by the first constructor?

Comment: *Every* constructor calls *a* parent constructor - explicitly (via `super(..)`) or implicitly though an assumed call-the-default-parent-constructor, possibly though another constructor (via `this(..)`) of the same type.

Answer (score 1):

> But is super called in every constructor, or only in the first
>   constructor of the subclass?

Firstly there is nothing like **first Constructor** or **Second Constructor** , Since Constructor calling will be based on Object Creation.

if you create Object this way

```
 new MyClass(); //then no-argument constructor will be called
```

and if Object Created in this way

```
new MyClass("ABC");// then parameterized constructor will be called
```

So `super()`  is called in each and every Constructor in the first line .

**Note** : if you explicitly call other constructor in the same class  using `this()` then in that scenario `super()` will not be called in existing constructor

Answer (score 0):

You can call another constructor from the same class like this:

MyClass(int someValue) {
  this(someValue, false);
  ....
}

In this case the super constructor is not called, but it will be called in the first constructor which doesn't call another constructor from the class.